# How to detect non-latin scripts in email subject?

Tags: postfix, spam

On my mail server running Postfix, I want to reject mails using some non-latin scripts in their subject, in particular Arabic and Cyrillic since none of my users (family) speak languages that use them.

I tried it with a PCRE header check like this:

```
/Subject:.*\p{Arabic}/i WARN Arabic detected
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't trigger a warning when I send a test mail to my server. I have verified that `WARN` messages do appear in the system log using a `/Subject:.*Test/i WARN Test` rule, which does trigger.

How can I detect Arabic and Cyrillic in the subject using Postfix?

For completeness, in my `main.cf` I include the `header_checks` like this:

```
header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [RFC 5322, 3.6.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6.5), the `Subject` header is defined as

> `subject         =   "Subject:" unstructured CRLF`

and the [RFC 5322, 2.2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-2.2.1) defines "unstructured":

> Some field bodies in this specification are defined simply as
> "unstructured" (which is specified in [section 3.2.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.2.5) as any printable
> US-ASCII characters plus white space characters) with no further
> restrictions.

Because only US-ASCII characters are allowed in the `Subject` header, any non-US-ASCII character must be encoded as US-ASCII, and [RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047) defines a *draft standard* for that, which is widely in use. E.g., with the "Quoted-Printable" a.k.a. "Q" encoding ([section 4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047#section-4.2)),

- cyrillic `Тест` becomes `Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?=D0=A2=D0=B5=D1=81=D1=82?=`
- arabic `متحان` becomes `Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?=D9=85=D8=AA=D8=AD=D8=A7=D9=86?=`.

The matching in PCRE `header_checks` should be done against that encoding. However, matching *unicode blocks* using regular expressions like PCRE is pretty hard, as the following table demonstrates.

| Unicode block | Range | Q-P start | Q-P end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [Cyrillic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_(Unicode_block)) | U+0400..U+04FF | `=D0=80` | `=D3=BF` |
| [Arabic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_(Unicode_block)) | U+0600..U+06FF | `=D8=80` | `=DB=BF` |

This limitation is also mentioned in the [Postfix Built-in Content Inspection](https://www.postfix.org/BUILTIN_FILTER_README.html) documentation:

> **Limitations of Postfix header/body checks**
>
> Header/body checks do not decode message headers or message body content. For example, if text in the message body is BASE64 encoded ([RFC 2045](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045)) then your regular expressions will have to match the BASE64 encoded form. Likewise, message headers with encoded non-ASCII characters ([RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047)) need to be matched in their encoded form.

I would suggest using SpamAssassin rules, instead. The [TextCat language guesser](https://spamassassin.apache.org/full/3.1.x/doc/Mail_SpamAssassin_Plugin_TextCat.html) even has `ok_languages` for detecting languages from message body.

Comment: That would already be hard to pull off without false-positives, but the mails I'm seeing are using the `B` encoding… Base 64. You can't do regular expressions on those. So I guess both you and @Zac67 are telling me "it can't be done with header_checks", but there surely must be _some_ way to reject such mails early, without accepting and passing to something like SpamAssassin first.

Comment: That's true. I added a citation from the official documentation stating the same. if you want to reject these mails with SpamAssassin rules, you could place it as a [Postfix before-queue Milter](https://www.postfix.org/MILTER_README.html). That will add some delay before accepting messages, which might cause problems with some MTAs. On the other hand, SpamAssassin could only have a few rules on that phase and be used again later with a different set of rules.

Comment: Good idea, using a "fast checks only" SpamAssassin setup would indeed solve my question and help with rejecting some other stuff early as well.

Answer (score 1):

[RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047) defines how to encode non-ASCII character sets into the *Subject* header.

Essentially, it uses the `=?charset?encoding?encoded-text?=` where `charset` can be any character set as defined for MIME like `UTF-8`, `encoding` is `B` for base64 or `Q` for quoted printable, and `encoded-text` is the actual subject line. Just look at the source code from one of those encoded messages and you'll get the idea.

Comment: Do you mean that Postfix only passes the _encoded_ subject to the `header_checks`, and there's no way to check the _decoded_ subject here?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Postfix only handles the encoded headers and leaves decoding to the email client.